# Open problem in math that just needs differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function and assume that
$f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon),$ I would like to know if it is true that $\frac{1}{\left\lvert f(x) \right\rvert} \le \frac{C}{\left\lvert x \right\rvert}$ for some $C>0$ in a neighborhood of zero?

Comment: This is true if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)\neq 0$ from the definition of a derivative. I'm confused by why there's so many additional assumptions.

Comment: "open problem" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Let $a=f'(0)>0$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=a$ tells us that $\frac{f(x)}{x}>\frac12a$ for small enough (but non-zero) $x$. This implies that you can ake $C=\frac2a$